# How can I clear react form hook after submit

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-hook-form

I want to empty/clear the function form react-hook-form but after submitting the input fields are not emptying. I don't know why exactly, I"m sure I"m missing something.

Here's my code:

```
const AddItem = () => {

const { register, handleSubmit } = useForm();
const onSubmit = data => {
    console.log(data);
    const url = 'http://localhost:5000/list'
    fetch(url, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'content-type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(data)
    })
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(result => {
            console.log(result);
        });
}

return (
    <div>
        <h1>Add item</h1>

        <form className='mt-5' onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
            <input className='mb-2' placeholder='name'{...register("Name", { required: true, maxLength: 20 })} />
            <br />
            <input className='mb-2' placeholder='Photo url' {...register("pic")} />
            <br />
            <input className='mb-2' type="number" placeholder='Give rating'{...register("rating")} />
            <br />
            <input type="submit" />
        </form>
    </div>
);
};
```

Comment: https://react-hook-form.com/api/useform/reset

Comment: You can use like this -                                                                                          
const { isSubmitSuccessful } = formState;
useEffect(() => {
      reset()
    }, [isSubmitSuccessful ]);

Answer (score -1):

`useForm` provides `reset` function. You can use that.

```
const AddItem = () => {

const { register, handleSubmit, reset } = useForm();
const onSubmit = data => {
    console.log(data);
    const url = 'http://localhost:5000/list'
    fetch(url, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'content-type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(data)
    })
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(result => {
            console.log(result);
            reset() // reset on success
        });
}

return (
    <div>
        <h1>Add item</h1>

        <form className='mt-5' onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
            <input className='mb-2' placeholder='name'{...register("Name", { required: true, maxLength: 20 })} />
            <br />
            <input className='mb-2' placeholder='Photo url' {...register("pic")} />
            <br />
            <input className='mb-2' type="number" placeholder='Give rating'{...register("rating")} />
            <br />
            <input type="submit" />
        </form>
    </div>
);
};
```